# The compressed linux kernel is too large

Tags: linux-kernel

I try to backup the linux kernel. But the .tar.gz file is so large which is about 2GB. Why the .tar.gz file I donwloaded before is only about 100MB?

Comment: Did you run a `make clean` before re-archiving?

Comment: @Jason no. let me try

Comment: the tar.gz file is now 200mb, the original tar.gz is 112mb. But I only modify several files, why it incur 80mb change? @Jason

Comment: The kernel sources are strictly text, which compresses extremely well.  When you build in the source directory, it builds binaries which won't compress well at all.  `make clean` will clean all the intermediates, but still leave the kernel binaries (arch/{arch}/kernel/).  The rest of the space I would guess is just a difference in compression level for gzip.

Comment: @Jason what gzip compression level would linux.org use when release those gzip file?

Comment: I think you mean kernel.org.  Most likely the highest compression level (-9).

Comment: Try a `make mrproper`.